# Problems accessing my strings.xml items.... i got numbers and not the string value

Tags: android, string

when from a java class i try to acces a item of my strings.xml file, i got numbers, like a mem position, and i dont get the string value of the item

for example:

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals(R.string.perdayspermission))
```

this code: `R.string.perdayspermission` haves to give me "Per Days", but it gives me a extrange number: 234552634

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getString() e.g.,

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals(getString(R.string.perdayspermission)))
```

Comment: If im not mistaken you have to write ClassName.this.getString, instead of just getString. I might be wrong though.

Comment: It's actually android.content.Context.getString(int resId) and it's how I get my strings from R.string

Comment: what? android content context? can you give me a code example with my code please?

Comment: @Falmarri - oops, that's true. I just realised I import context explicitly for another reason

Comment: Is this from within an android activity or is it a 'generic' (non-android) java class?

Comment: IT STILL DOESN'T WORKS, no one know why?

Comment: ok it works, sorry mates, my fault, i failed with other thing, but this wortks, thanks!

Comment: @AndroidUser99 - lol, no worries it happens to all of us from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because R.string.perdayspermission is simply a numerical reference to where that string can be found. Try:

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perdayspermission))
```

Update:

```
String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
String test = getResources().getString(R.string.perdayspermission);
Log.i('test', 'item: '+item);
Log.i('test', 'test: '+test);
if(item.compareTo(test)==0)Log.i('test', 'strings match');
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the answer, I have updated it. What error do you get?

Comment: no error, it simply doesn't works, it still gets numbers and not the string item